# type parameters for context subtype

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have com across this construct several times now for classes and methods bout I don't understand why you would use:

```
class MyClass[C <: Context](ctx: C)
```

instead of:

```
class MyClass(ctx: Context)
```

Is it to get around covariance or something?

Another question would be the following:

```
abstract class YYTransformer[C <: Context, T](c: C, t: T) {
     type Ctx = C
}
```

why not simply use:

```
type Ctx = c.type
```

Thanks

Comment: re: your second question, `.type` doesn't mean what you think it means. `c.type` is a singleton type. e.g. `3.type` isn't `Int` (the type of all ints), it's `3.type` (a singleton type of which 3 is the only instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Question 1

They are basically the same, except for the fact that in:

```
class MyClass[C <: Context](ctx: C)
```

you keep track of the class of the ctx variable.
In this way, it's possible to do something like:

```
class MyClass[C <: Context](ctx: C) {
  val m: List[C]
}
```

that would be impossible with:

```
class MyClass(ctx: Context) {
  val m : List[???]
}
```

#### Question 2

As previously stated by [Seth Tisue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86485/seth-tisue), `.type` doesn't return the type of the object you're calling `.type` on, but a singleton type, that is a type that "suits" only such object.

Comment: Hm ok, I thought there was something more specific to macros why this needed to be done this way...